# search or filter php array for a particular value and return outer index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have defined a multi-dimensional array in php and I want to get the index of the 1st level, where a specific inner key has a certain value:

```
$arr = [
    [ [ "a" => "one",   "b" => "two", ],
      [ "a" => "three", "b" => "four", ],   
    ],
    [ [ "a" => "five",  "b" => "six", ],
      [ "a" => "seven", "b" => "eight", ],  
    ],
];
```

I want to get the index $i of the 1st level, where $arr[$i][$j]["b"] == "six".
Thus $arr[$i] should resolve to:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(4) "five"
    ["b"]=>
    string(3) "six"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(5) "seven"
    ["b"]=>
    string(5) "eight"
  }
}
```

I could do this with a loop:

```
function getIndex($needle, $haystack) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($haystack); $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($haystack[$i]); $j++) {
            if ( $haystack[$i][$j]['b'] == $needle ) {
                return $i;
            }
        }
    }
}

$x = $arr[ getIndex('six', $arr) ];
var_dump($x);
```

Can I achieve this without interation loops? With an expression to filter or search the array, like
`$x = $arr[ <expression> ];`

Comment: What sort of thing would you want for `<expression>`?

Comment: @NigelRen That's a good question! Actually, I'm looking for a php language element equivalent of my getIndex() function. If I was searching for a value in a one-dimensional array, I could use array_search(). The result would be the key that I could use to address the element, like $x = $arr[ array_search($needle, $arr) ] - which is trival as $x==$needle. Now I want to search for the value at a deeper level and I already know the name of it's key. The return should be the index of the outer (1st) level, where the condition is meet.

Comment: Your nested loops with conditional early `return` is going to perform better than Nigel's answer because `array_filter()` will continue to iterate the subset even after finding a qualifying row.  Why do you want to replace the most performant approach? @Jam  I recommend [this refined approach](https://3v4l.org/YFmsT).

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, I realize that the loops are the best approach. I was coming from a Powershell mindset where you can SELECT with WHERE clauses and refine your search conditions or use regex MATCHes. And thanks for the 3v4l link, that I'll put on my list of useful tools.

Answer (score 1):

A flexible way of trying to achieve this would be to pass a callback to the search function.  This callback would be used to filter the data, only if there is a match will there be some data and this can be used to return the index where it matches.

So first a callback which would check the element of the array...

```
function check($haystack)
{
    return $haystack['b'] == 'six';
}
```

Then the function itself...

```
function getIndex(callable $filter, array $haystack)
{
    // Loop the base level of the array
    foreach ($haystack as $index => $subArray) {
        // If applying the filter method leaves some data, then it's found
        if (array_filter($subArray, $filter)) {
            return $index;
        }
    }

    // Return false for not found
    return false;
}
```

Then the actual usage

```
var_dump(getIndex('check', $arr));
```